# How can I check each first character of each line in a Streamread?

Tags: c#

I'm currently struggling with a C# question since I'm new into the language.

case:

I have a text file. Inside this text file, there will be a formatted text. 
I have to open this file in C# using the `streamreader`, this I managed to do so far. 
Then, I have to check each line separately, also this, (I think) I did. 
But now, I want to check the first character in this line, if it's either an "S" or a "B".

If the first character is "B", I will have to use a different class to format the output in my `listbox`.

A screenshot of a text file is included here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTBh0.jpg

```
        String line = ""; 
        ...
    private void MenuItem_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        string startfolder = 
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = startfolder;
        openFileDialog.Filter = "txt Files| *.txt";

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        { // user clicks open
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog.FileName);
            while(line != null)
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                if (line[0].Equals("B") || line[0].Equals("b"))
                {
                    performListBox.Items.Add(line);

                }

                   //performListBox.Items.Add(line);


            }
            sr.Close();

        }

    }
```

Currently, I get the response that line = null. It tells me I'm dealing with characters in a certain way..

Comment: If you get a null then you've reached the end of the file.  So use `if (line == null) break;` to get out of the loop.  Some programmers favor `while (true)`, some favor `for (;;)` to write this kind of loop.

Comment: If you want to add `line` to a `ListBox`, you need to create a `ListBoxItem` as follows : `performListBox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem(line, "value"));`.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the line variable before getting any line from the file at the first loop. And use == with single quote ''  over Equal() function
Change this area:

```
while(line != null)
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            if (line[0].Equals("B") || line[0].Equals("b"))
            {
                performListBox.Items.Add(line);

            }

               //performListBox.Items.Add(line);


        }
```

to this

```
line = sr.ReadLine();
while(line != null)
{
    if (line[0] =='B') || line[0] == 'b'))
    {
        performListBox.Items.Add(line);
    }
        //performListBox.Items.Add(line);
    line = sr.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, this makes total sense now.